# Would like Excel VBA to refer to open workbook starting with

Tags: vba, excel, macros

We work off multiple reports that all start with the name of the report and end with the date in the same format every time, such as 'Example Report 28.09.16.xls'.

I am trying to show results from one workbook in another workbook when they are both open at the same time, is there anyway to make this work using left function or contains so that I can open any combination of 2 reports and they will pull over irrelevant of the date?

```
Windows("Example Report 28.09.16.xls").Activate
```

Or

```
=VLOOKUP(B1,'[Example Report 28.09.16.xls]Sheet1'!$B$1:$C$10,2,FALSE)
```

I would prefer this to be a macro but a formula version would be good also.

As above I need the date to be able to be anything else, as the person opening the report will open the relevant report at the same time.

The goal is to have an item that is referenced in a number of reports show all the data for each report next to that item in one report.

Does anyone know of how I can do this or any better way around this?

EDIT

Another idea ive just had, is there a way to piece together the window to activate by using the 'Right' function to pull the date from the filename of the current file open then add it to the static report name I am referencing? such as:

```
Dim ReportDate As String

ReportDate = Right(ThisWorkbook.FullName,12)

Dim ReportName As String

ReportName = "Example Report "

Windows( ReportName + ReportName ).Activate
```

Comment: Look at Regular Expressions to perform the necessary pattern matching on the filenames.  If I get time later (and nobody else has done so already) I'll put together a fuller answer for you

Answer (score 0):

You could ask the user to select the files to open, or use some way of getting a valid date (maybe a calendar control) and then use the references to those workbooks in the code.

The code below will ask for the location of the file (using the `GetFile1` function) and open that.  It will then open the file with todays date on the users desktop (`GetFile`) - just pass a different date for a different file.

It will then grab the value from cell A1 in the two workbooks and place those values in cells A1:A2 of the workbook containing the code.

```
Public Sub Test()

    Dim wrkBk1 As Workbook
    Dim wrkBk2 As Workbook

    Set wrkBk1 = Workbooks.Open(GetFile1)
    Set wrkBk2 = Workbooks.Open(GetFile(Date))

    'ThisWorkbook is the file containing this code.
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        .Cells(1, 1) = wrkBk1.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1) 'Get the value from A1 and place in A1.
        .Cells(2, 1) = wrkBk2.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1) 'Get the value from A1 and place in A2.
    End With

End Sub

Function GetFile1(Optional startFolder As Variant = -1) As Variant
    Dim fle As FileDialog
    Dim vItem As Variant
    Set fle = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    With fle
        .Title = "Select a File"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xls*", 1
        If startFolder = -1 Then
            .InitialFileName = Application.DefaultFilePath
        Else
            If Right(startFolder, 1) <> "\" Then
                .InitialFileName = startFolder & "\"
            Else
                .InitialFileName = startFolder
            End If
        End If
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        vItem = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
NextCode:
    GetFile = vItem
    Set fle = Nothing
End Function


Function GetFile(dDate As Date) As Variant

    GetFile = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("Desktop") & "\Example Report " & Format(dDate, "dd.mm.yyyy") & ".xls"

End Function
```